# Gmail put my emails into spam folder

Tags: email, gmail, postfix-mta

I am really confused. I have tested my mail server with mail-tester.com, I got 10/10 but Gmail still puts my emails into spam folder.

I have PTR, DKIM and SPF records, all valid.

The mailserver hostname is: domain.tld

The email viewed from the destination:

```html
Delivered-To: email
Received: by 10.176.71.30 with SMTP id h30csp57228uac;
        Wed, 3 May 2017 06:54:08 -0700 (PDT)
X-Received: by 10.28.35.207 with SMTP id j198mr6661610wmj.17.1493819648744;
        Wed, 03 May 2017 06:54:08 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <eamil>
Received: from ironforge.meatkult.com (diamondshine.hu. [31.14.134.231])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id n6si7712651wra.196.2017.05.03.06.54.08
        for <email>
        (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
        Wed, 03 May 2017 06:54:08 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of eamil designates 31.14.134.231 as permitted sender) client-ip=31.14.134.231;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@meatkult.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of email designates 31.14.134.231 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=email
Received: from localhost (ironforge.meatkult.com [127.0.0.1]) by ironforge.meatkult.com (Postfix) with ESMTP id C0D5561DE3 for <email>; Wed,
  3 May 2017 15:54:07 +0200 (CEST)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/simple; d=meatkult.com; h= content-transfer-encoding:content-type:content-type:mime-version :user-agent:date:date:message-id:subject:subject:from:from; s= default; t=1493819647; x=1495634048; bh=gSWT9V3EBSVx0zLNz5M9KT0K Z1jXGsJ1lUMr6hpFhDU=; b=gcFh4x2hIg9hXPzOzokAZBF8ewYZQk1+sVtlq2r6 TsBQcZU+8fdswJoBgrt/9y2nXc+zfyE8dZiGoqnndXRyvfzKC7IF2aIjTcoZzHxW UdH7GTT7cn3FTur6ceaOi6BGIXzbN+ovNr8+SC7fvO9f6r3xxb/4op4qoT3GpQXA LO4=
X-Virus-Scanned: Debian amavisd-new at ironforge.meatkult.com
Received: from ironforge.meatkult.com ([127.0.0.1]) by localhost (ironforge.meatkult.com [127.0.0.1]) (amavisd-new, port 10026) with ESMTP id 9mCr5x49RMat for <email>; Wed,
  3 May 2017 15:54:07 +0200 (CEST)
Received: from [192.168.1.163] (s10.ip4.lp01.wwdh.hu [217.65.97.10]) (Authenticated sender: arape@meatkult.com) by ironforge.meatkult.com (Postfix) with ESMTPSA id 55FDB6027A for <emial>; Wed,
  3 May 2017 15:54:07 +0200 (CEST)
To: email
From: Peter Arany <email>
Subject: I don't know what's going on
Message-ID: <a41512a6-eddc-7fd1-d897-37415b7ed766@meatkult.com>
Date: Wed, 3 May 2017 15:53:27 +0200
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Thunderbird/45.8.0
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8; format=flowed
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Still not receiving mails
```

I have valid SSL certification by letsencrypt, I think everything should be fine, but its not. Does anyone has experience in this case? Did I miss something?

Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your filters. You may have some filters to move your mails to Spam Folder. You can learn about filters here - https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6579?hl=en

Comment: Thank you, time solved the problem I think, It is okay now